# How is line break handled under Windows and why it affect text rendering in some editor

Tags: c, windows, notepad

I copied an excerpt from a PDF and paste on Sublime Text.  The excerpt came with line break:

[image: With line break]

I wrote a small C program to remove line break.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
int main(){
    FILE* in = fopen("feynman.txt","r");
    FILE* out = fopen("feynmanStripped.txt","w");
    assert(in!=NULL && out!=NULL);
    int c;
        c = fgetc(in);
        while(c!=EOF){
        if(c!='\n')
            fputc(c,out);
        c = fgetc(in);
    } 
}
```

The program was executed under Cygwin.

The resulting text was opened in Sublime Text and Notepad:
[image]

As you can see, line break disappear in Notepad, but not in Sublime Text.
I also tried to read/write as `"rb"`/`"wb"` mode, but it didn't make a difference.

I guess it might be due to how Windows deals with `'\n'` and `'\r'`, which affects how Sublime Text and Notepad render the text.  What is working under the hood?

( Note : I also copy/paste the same text to MS Word, the result is same as in ST )

Comment: Search is your friend. The handling of endlines has been a point of confusion between Windows and other platforms for many years. In fact, `fopen` offers options for dealing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. Yes, this is related to the whole `\r\n` thing, there's no other sane explanation unless your files were mangled in strange ways. It is a little odd, though, that this happens when you're opening files in text mode under Windows; you'd expect the mapping to be done for you. There's something rotten in the state of Cygwin, and fortunately it is documented [here](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-textbinary.html).

Long story short: You're not opening the file in text mode. This is surprising because the C standard rather says that your code should be doing that, but Cygwin strays from the path here. Instead, you're opening the file in what the Cygwin docs call **default mode**. Whether default mode does the Windows newline mapping depends on a number of things such as whether the file path is specified as a UNIX or Windows path, how the file system a UNIX path resolves to is "mounted," how you linked the program and other stuff (follow the link for details). This leaves you several ways to resolve the problem:

- Link with `-ltextmode`, forcing default mode to mean text mode,
- `fopen("feynman.txt", "rt")` (note: this is not, strictly speaking, standard-conforming code),
- `fopen(".\\feynman.txt", "r")` (force a windows path)
- `if(c != '\n' && c != '\r') ...`
- maybe others, but those are the ones I can think of right now.